# drop down list 1st value is saving to database others are not saving

Tags: php, laravel

while am fetching the data from the drop down list the first value only saving. here am using the 3 drop down for saving the day. start time and end time. the days are correctly coming but the times are not coming correctly the first time that i selected from the 1st drop down list are coming.

i want the output like this:
moday 8.00 12.00
tuesday 7.00 12.00

but whwn i run the code the out is geting:
monday 8.00 12.00
tuesday 8.00 12.00

please resolve my problem. the code is given below:

blade file:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                           <h4 class="card-title"><b>Business Hours</b></h4>
                           <br />
                           
                        <div>
<div>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center form-time">
                                    <div class="col item form-group day">
                                       <select class="form-control" name="day[]">
                                          <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                                          <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                          <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                                          <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                                          <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                                          <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                                          <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col item form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" name="start_time[]">
                                          <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
                                          <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                                          <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                                          <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                                          <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                                          <option value="12:00">12::00</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col item form-group">
                                       <select class="form-control" name="end_time[]">
                                          <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                                          <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                                          <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                                          <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                                          <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                                          <option value="18:00">18::00</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2"><span class="btn btn-primary" id="businesshrAdd"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></div>


                                 </div>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="attachFileTemplate"></div>
    </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center"><button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Create</button></div>
                        
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                     </div><!-- END card-->
               </div>
            </div><!-- END row-->
         </div>
      </section><!-- Page footer-->


@section('pagespecificscripts')

<script>
    $('#businesshrAdd').click(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMilliseconds();
        var template = '<div style="margin-top:15px;" id="div_'+n+'"><div class="form-row align-items-center form-time"><div class="col item form-group day"><select class="form-control" name="day[]"><option value="Monday">Monday</option><option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option><option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option><option value="Thursday">Thursday</option><option value="Friday">Friday</option><option value="Saturday">Saturday</option><option value="Sunday">Sunday</option></select></div><div class="col item form-group"><select class="form-control" name="start_time[]"><option value="07.00">07:00</option><option value="08.00">08:00</option><option value="09.00">09:00</option><option value="10.00">10:00</option><option value="11.00">11:00</option><option value="12.00">12::00</option></select></div><div class="col item form-group"><select class="form-control" name="end_time[]"><option value="13.00">13:00</option><option value="14.00">14:00</option><option value="15.00">15:00</option><option value="16.00">16:00</option><option value="17.00">17:00</option><option value="18.00">18::00</option></select></div><div class="col-md-2"><span class="btn btn-primary delBtn" id="'+n+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></div><br /><br /></div>';
        $('#attachFileTemplate').append(template);
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".delBtn", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#div_'+id).remove();
    });
    
</script>

@stop
```

controller:

```
if ($day = $request->input('day') && $start_time = $request->input('start_time') && $end_time = $request->input('end_time') ) {
                foreach ($request->input('day') as $days) 
                {
                    $brandhr = new BrandHr();
                    
                           
                    foreach ($request->input('start_time') as $start_times) 
                    {
                        
                        foreach ($request->input('end_time') as $end_times) 
                        {
                            $brandhr->end_time = $end_times;
                            break;
                            
                        }
                        echo $start_times."   ";
                        $brandhr->start_time = $start_times;
                        break;
                    }
                     $brandhr->listing_id = $model->id;
                            $brandhr->day = $days;
                            $brandhr->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $brandhr->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $brandhr->save();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I do not see value attribute in your options, am I missing anything?

Comment: when i give the option value same error is occuring

Comment: try without your `break`s

Comment: problem was not changing.. the days are properly coming but the time is same on all days. ie when i select the time for monday start time as 7 and end time as 12. on tuesday wed the same time is showing on database